# codeigniter with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I would like to use jQuery inside CodeIngiter Project. I don't know whats wrong because it doesn't work out, here is my code

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo  base_url(); ?>inc/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

also   `autoload.php` file

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');
```

Comment: did you check the base url getting is correct??

Comment: which version of code igniter you are using

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/school_management/';           using CodeIgniter-3.0.3

Comment: Have you placed the js inside a assets folder **out side** of application?

Comment: yes @wolfgang1983

Comment: Have you placed it in the head area of html

Answer (score 0):

### Codeigniter Using JQuery

The jQuery Class
To initialize the jQuery class manually in your controller constructor, use the `$this->load->library()` method:

```
$this->load->library('javascript/jquery');
```

You may send an optional parameter to determine whether or not a script tag for the main jQuery file will be automatically included when loading the library. It will be created by default. To prevent this, load the library as follows:

`$this->load->library('javascript/jquery', FALSE)`;
Once loaded, the jQuery library object will be available using:

```
$this->jquery
```

jQuery Events
Events are set using the following syntax.

```
$this->jquery->event('element_path', code_to_run());
```

For More help [Codeigniter JQuery](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set this before

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo  base_url(); ?>inc/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Or before

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo  base_url(); ?>inc/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```